# Continous periodic function is uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x+1)=f(x)\forall x$ we need to show $f$ is uniformly continuous function.

please give me some hint:

Comment: Hint: Note that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: well, I knew that $f$ is uniformly continous on any $[x,x+1]$, can I say $f$ is uniformly continuos on $\mathbb{R}$ directly?

Comment: Use the periodicity....

Comment: @Panu It's not enough without your other assumption. $f(x)=x^2$ is uniformly continuous on any closed interval but is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I really not getting, please explain a bit more

Comment: You have uniform continuity on any $[x,x+1]$ this doesn't give uniform continuity on $\mathbb{R}$; $f(x)=x^2$ is an example that is uniformly continuous on any $[x,x+1]$ but not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore you need to apply $f(x)=f(x+1)$ in some way. What Tomas and user108903 are suggesting is that since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ and $f$ is periodic with period 1, if you want a $\delta$ for some $\epsilon$ and you need to consider $x \notin [0,1]$ you can use the periodicity to identify $x$ with some $y\in[0,1]$.

Comment: on $[0,1]$fix $\epsilon>0$, then we will get a $\delta>0$ such that for any $x_1,x_2$ with $|x_1-x_2|<\delta$ we have  $f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\epsilon$, now for this $\epsilon$ I can take $x=x_2-1\in [0,1]$ and $y=x_2\in [0,1]^c$ so that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $f(x)-f(y)=0$?